# HTML5 Offline Storage Functionality not working

Tags: html

I have created one webpage having images, text and CSS. Deployed it into local IIS server. Set mime type ".manifest" into it.

While checking the page in FireFox, it asks me weather I want to allow to store offline. Even though I allow it, FF shows only 0 bytes stored into the cache.

Please revert if anyone has the solution.

Comment: `.manifest` isn't a MIME type, it's a file extension.  What is the MIME type you've set for the `.manifest` file extension, and what are the contents of your manifest file?

Comment: yes, I mean that I have set mime type for .manifest file as text/cache-manifest. 
Below are the details for manifest file:

CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:

index.html
images/arrow.png
css/style.css
js/test.js

Answer (score 0):

Debug your cache manifest file. If there are any errors at all, your appcache won't work.

[Debugging HTML 5 Offline Application Cache](http://jonathanstark.com/blog/2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/)

**UPDATE**
Other steps to take when checking your cache manifest:

Use the debug code linked above to check that the user agent is actually detecting that something's changed, and downloads the updates, with a cache swap, accordingly. If this doesn't happen, edit your cache file and re-save it (be sure to change its byte signature when you do this, else the change won't be detected). You should definitely see activity in your console -- if not, something's wrong with the cache manifest.

Double-check that the cache manifest content type is correct. It sounds like it's set right at the IIS end, but it can't hurt to be sure. You can do this either by examining the cache manifest headers in Firebug (or similar), or by issuing a command like this in a shell:

```
curl -I http://yourdomain/path/to/manifest_file.manifest
```

If all is well, you should see something similar to this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Length: 1039
Content-Type: text/cache-manifest
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with FF (I debug my off-line stuff in WebKit) but do you know for sure that nothing is getting stored? Where do you get the '0 bytes stored into the cache' information from? Have you tried taking FF off-line and seeing if the page(s) render still or not?

Comment: You can see the stored cache ---> FF ->TOOLS ->OPTIONS->ADVANCED TAG ->NETWORK TAB

Comment: Yes I see it. In that case, there is a problem with your cache manifest. I've updated my answer.